# ¿Por qué me sigue mostrando la comilla simple en el textbox?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando hacer una validación para no utilizar comilla simple `''` en un textbox. Tengo este evento en KeyPress, entra a la condición y me muestra el mensaje pero sigue mostrando la comilla en el control.

```
 private void txtNotas_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)39)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MostrarMensajeToolTip((Control)sender, this.Text, "Carácter no valido");
                return;
            }
        }
```

¿Qué estoy pasando por alto?

Comment: Revisa si necesitas el 39 o el 96. Son diferentes :)

Comment: puede ser que el problema esté en el método MostrarMensajeTooltip si es un método que has programado tú le puedes poner editando la pregunta?

Comment: el problema estaba en otra validación al determinar la descripción del textbox, permitía todos los caracteres y se contradecía lo que trataba de hacer, gracias por sus comentarios.